# No first derivative term, solve for $\alpha$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider $u_t=u_{xx}+cu_x+au,~a,c\in\mathbb{R}$, on $(-L,L)$ with homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions and look for solutions in $L^2([-L,L])$.

Consider $v=e^{\alpha x} u$ for $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ and $u\in L^2([-L,L])$. Find $\alpha$ such that the equation for $v$ has no first derivative term $v_x$.

As far as I see I can assume that $c\neq 0$ and I have to solve
$$
v_x=\alpha e^{\alpha x}u+e^{\alpha x}u_x=e^{\alpha x}(\alpha u+u_x)=0
$$

This is satisfied if either $e^{\alpha x}=0$ or $\alpha u+u_x=0$.

If $\alpha=0$, then we have $u_x=0$, i.e. $u$ has to be constant in space.

If $\alpha \neq 0$, then $e^{\alpha x}$ cannot be $0$ on $[-L,L]$ so we need to have $\alpha u+u_x=0$

Now, I do not know how to solve for $\alpha$. Maybe I misunderstood something or made a mistake. Would be great to get some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$v=e^{\alpha x}u \quad\to\quad u=e^{-\alpha x}v$$

$$u_x=e^{-\alpha x} (-\alpha v+v_x)$$

$$u_{xx}=e^{-\alpha x}(\alpha^2v-2\alpha v_x+v_{xx})$$

$$u_t=u_{xx}+cu_x+au =e^{-\alpha x}v_t=e^{-\alpha x}(\alpha^2v-2\alpha v_x+v_{xx} +c(-\alpha v+v_x) +av)$$

$$v_t=(c-2\alpha) v_x+v_{xx} +(a+\alpha^2-c\alpha) v $$

$$c=2\alpha \quad\to\quad v_t=v_{xx} +(a+\alpha^2-c\alpha) v $$
$$v_t=v_{xx} +(a-\alpha^2) v $$